# Declaring functions of two different smart contracts inside a single interface

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap, interfaces

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

interface IUniswap {
  function swapExactTokensForETH(
    uint amountIn, 
    uint amountOutMin, 
    address[] calldata path, 
    address to, 
    uint deadline)
    external
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
  function WETH() external pure returns (address);
}

interface IERC20 {
  function transferFrom(
    address sender, 
    address recipient, 
    uint256 amount) 
    external 
    returns (bool);
}

contract MyDeFiProject {
  IUniswap uniswap;

  constructor(address _uniswap) {
    uniswap = IUniswap(_uniswap);
  }

  function swapTokensForEth(address token, uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, uint deadline) external {
    IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(DAI);
    path[1] = uniswap.WETH();
    IERC20(token).approve(address(uniswap), amountIn);
    uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(
      amountIn, 
      amountOutMin, 
      path, 
      msg.sender, 
      deadline
    );
  }
}
```

In the above interface `IUniswap`, the function `swapExactTokensForETH` has been taken from **IUniswapV2Router02.sol**, whereas, the function `WETH` has been taken from **IUniswapV2Router01.sol**. This has been shown in the YouTube channel of *EatTheBlocks*. [This is the video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Im5iaYoz1Y)

**My question is how is it possible to call two different functions of separate smart contracts from the same interface?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because IUniswapV2Router02.sol inherits IUniswapV2Router01.sol. Therefore you may think of Router02 interface as an extension of Router01 interface with all of its functions.